# Required sample size for exact McNemar test and for phi coefficient (power analysis)

Tags: r, sample-size, statistical-power, contingency-tables, mcnemar-test

I aim to establish the required sample size for my study. In the main analyses, which are conducted to test my hypotheses, I am investigating two **2x2 tables**. Specifically, I plan to perform an **exact McNemar test** for the first table (with a **directed p-value**) and to examine the **phi coefficient** for the second table. For the McNemar test, my focus is on comparing values in the lower-left versus upper-right cell. How can I conduct a power analysis to determine the necessary sample size with alpha = $0.05$ and power = $0.8$? Is it feasible to perform this analysis in either R (e.g., using a simulation) or G*Power?

Comment: Hi Louis! For conducting an *a priori* power analysis (i.e. finding the required sample size), you also have to determine what minimal effect size you want to be able to detect in your population of interest.

Comment: Note that McNemar's test is equivalent to a sign test; an exact test would be be based on the binomial; it's not at all hard to do a one-tailed version. This calculation is quite simple. Conversely an exact test for phi - were you to want one - could be performed if you condition on the margins, in almost exactly the same manner as the exact version of a chi-squared test is done in R (see `?chisq.test` there), using Patefield's algorithm for sampling the 2x2 tables. There's a function `r2dtable` which implements the algorithm in question and facilitates working with any statistic you like.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled "Power analysis McNemar test" and found this [web page](https://www.scalestatistics.com/sample-size-for-mcnemars-test.html) from ScaleStatistics, describing, in detail, how to do it in GPower. It allows both directional and non-directional tests.

I didn't find a GPower implementation for phi (although it may exist) but Unistat has one, see [this site](https://www.unistat.com/guide/sample-size-and-power-phi-distribution/) .

As for simulation, if you are clever enough, I think you can simulate a power analysis for almost anything. I am not a programmer, but I don't think either of these should be that difficult (but I may be wrong).